# General solution to trigonometric equation $2\sin(3x) = \sqrt{3}$

Tags: trigonometry

After finding the trigonòmetric eqaution can someone help me find the values of x as I'm not really sure what to do

Find the values of $x$ for which $2\sin(3x)= \sqrt{3}$.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: I have divided by 3   *after* getting solution. Doing it before and you cannot return. $ \sin 3x = \sin 60^{\circ};\, 3x= 60^{\circ},120^{\circ}.. so,.. x=20^{\circ},40^{\circ} \,;$

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so you want to solve $\sin 3x = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$.

Letting $\alpha = 3x$ you can rewrite $\sin \alpha = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, which is an elementary equation you can solve using tables: in fact, $\sin \alpha = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ iff $\alpha = 60^\circ \lor \alpha = 120^\circ$. Since the values of the sine of an angle repeat themselves every $360^\circ$ (i.e., $\sin \alpha$ is a $360^\circ$-periodic function), each angle in the form:
$$\tag{A} \alpha = 60^\circ + k 360^\circ \lor \alpha = 120^\circ + k 360^\circ$$
 (with $k \in \mathbb{Z}$) is a solution of $\sin \alpha = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ too and no other solution exists.

Now, in order to find your initial unknown $x$, all you have to do is to substitute back $3x=\alpha$ in (A) and solve for $x$. You’ll get:

$$\tag{B} x = 20^\circ + k 120^\circ \lor x = 40^\circ + k 120^\circ$$

Comment: Can you help me find the values of x for whuch that equation. 0°<x<360°

Answer (score 1):

Working in degrees,

$$2\sin 3x=\sqrt{3}\iff\sin 3x=\sin60^\circ=\sin120^\circ\\\iff\exists n\in\Bbb Z\left(3x=60^\circ+360n^\circ\lor3x=120^\circ+360n^\circ\right)\\\iff\exists n\in\Bbb Z\left(x=(20+120n)^\circ\lor x=(40+120n)^\circ\right).$$